# MVVM and SingleSelectionModel in ComboBoxes in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, mvvm, data-binding

I'm having trouble doing wiring a `ComboBox.selectionModelProperty` to my ViewModel.

The problem resides that the property is of type `SingleSelectionModel`, which is an interface and not really easy to instantiate. My idea was to instantiate a `ObjectProperty<SingleSelectionModel>` in the ViewModel and then bind it to `ComboBox.selectionModelProperty`.

```
class ViewModel {
  val selectedService = new SimpleObjectProperty[SingleSelectionModel[ServiceId]]()
  ..

  // I want to set an initial value but now I have a problem.. 
  // there's no easy way of instantiating a SingleSelectionModel 
  // without resorting to roll out my own implementation of a 
  // SingleSelectionModel.
}
```

1. I assume this must be a common issue to whoever is doing MVVM (or something similar, for that matter), or am I doing something wrong?
2. My take is that it makes sense for the ViewModel to always create its properties / bindings and then have the View's code-behind to apply the bindings -- it should be "in control" of the life-cycle of its properties/bindings and that includes their creation. Am I correct?
3. Another option would be to have in my ViewModel just a property with the value my selection would take (let's say, a Color) and then it would be up to the View to do the conversion to a `SingleSelectionModel`, but it seems to me that the APIs are not really geared towards that. Are they?

Thanks!

Comment: don't understand the problem .. (and SingleSelectionModel is-not an interface but an abstract class, doesn't really matter, though) Please provide some outline in code to demonstrate what's wrong

Comment: Hi @kleopatra, I provided an example.

Comment: hmm .. which aspect of the selectionModel are you really interested in?

Comment: @kleopatra: I want to be able to be able to set the combobox's selection from my viewmodel.

Comment: which of it, item or index or both or something else? Whatever, you can write a simple "selectionModel" in your viewModel layer plus an adapter that bridges the gap between your model and the combo's ..

Comment: well, both (I'm still not very well versed on how javafx works -- I don't know if it internally is keeping track of the selected object itself or if of the object's index in the array of available values).

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38506800/230513) outlines an approach.