# How to use TabPane tabs and selection model in MVVM pattern in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, mvvm, javafx-bindings

I want to try to use `TabPane` in `MVVM` design. For this I need to separate `TabPane` tabs and selection model and make an unidirectional binding for tabs an bidirectional binding for selection model. So, I have

```
public class View {

    private final TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

    private void initialize() {
        Bindings.bindContent(this.tabPane.getTabs(), this.getViewModel().getTabPaneTabs());
        this.tabPane.selectionModelProperty()
            .bindBidirectional(this.getViewModel().getTabPaneSelectionModel()); ?????
    }

    public ViewModel getViewModel() {
        return this.viewModel;
    }
    ...
}

public class ViewModel {

    private final ObservableList<Tab> tabPaneTabs = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    private final SingleSelectionModel<Tab> tabPaneSelectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<Tab>() {

        @Override
        protected Tab getModelItem(int index) {
            return tabPaneTabs.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        protected int getItemCount() {
            return tabPaneTabs.size();
        }
    };

    public ObservableList<Tab> getTabPaneTabs() {
        return tabPaneTabs;
    }

    public SingleSelectionModel<Tab> getTabPaneSelectionModel() {
        return tabPaneSelectionModel;
    }

    ....
}
```

I think my solution for tabs is correct (or I am wrong) but I can't find how to do binding with selection model. Could anyone help me?

Comment: You're conflating the View and the ViewModel.  The ViewModel has no knowledge of the inner workings of the View and it shouldn't even know about Tabs at all.  If you have a need to control Tab selection from outside the View, do it in a "data centric" way.  For instance, if you have a "Customers" Tab and an "Orders" Tab and you want the switch to the "Orders" tab when data is loaded for it after a Button in the "Customers" Tab is clicked - then have a data element called "OrderDataPresent", and use a ChangeListener in the View to make the "Orders" Tab selected when it changes to "true".

Comment: @DaveB I am afraid I don't agree with you. See this link https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX/wiki/MVVM-in-more-detail : The View defines how the UI looks like, what controls are used and what layout the UI has. The View doesn't contain any logic. For example, the View only knows that there is a button but not under which conditions this button is enabled or disabled or what happens when the button is pressed. I absolutely agree with it. All logic must be in `ViewModel` which doesn't know about `View`. For example it allows us to test `ViewModel` very easily.

Comment: The selection model for tabs is pretty simple, it can only be a single selection model, so rather than exposing the whole model, you could just expose the `selectedItem`, but it is a read-only property, so you can't bidirectionally bind it.  So, create a new read-write property, and when it changes have a listener update the actual selection to keep the properties in sync.  That is just my off-hand thought without giving your question a lot of consideration.

Comment: @Pavel_K The very same link you referenced says: “However, the ViewModel does not know about any specific controls.”. A `Tab` is a control. The ViewModel should have no knowledge of the tabs, and should not gave to change if you wanted to change the view so it didn’t use tabs or a tab pane at all.

Comment: @Pavel_K, your sample code has ObservableList<Tab> in the ViewModel.  As we've both said, the ViewModel should have no knowledge of the details of the View.  Tab is a View Node and should NEVER be referenced outside of the View.  By putting Tab into your ViewModel, your pulling elements of the View into the ViewModel.  Your Presentation Model, which is the data part of the ViewModel which is shared with the View, should contain elements which are updated by the business logic and used by the View to determine which Tab is selected.  But you don't select Tabs in the ViewModel.